# Group Collision Detection Not Working Properly

Tags: python, pygame, collision-detection

I am having problems with group collision. I am making a game with a gun and the 
mouse is the crosshair. When I touch the `enemy(group)`, the collision is not detected until I touch the only
enemy in the `corner(0,0)`. I want to be able to collide with all of the enemies moving across the screen. I
am using `pygame.sprite.spritecollideany()` for the collision code and I'm using `sys.exit()` for the output.

```
import pygame
import random
import sys
import os
from pygame.locals import *

#Initialize pygame
pygame.init()

#Window properties
window_width = 1366
window_height = 768
window = pygame.display.set_mode((window_width,window_height),pygame.FULLSCREEN)
pygame.display.set_caption("Sniper")

#Clock
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

#Movement
moveX = 1
moveY = 0

#Colors
black = (0,0,0)
white = (255,255,255)
blue = (0,0,64)

#Sprite groups
enemies = pygame.sprite.Group()
cursors = pygame.sprite.Group()

#Enemy
class Enemy(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = 25
        self.height = 100
        self.image = pygame.image.load('graphic\\sprite\\spr_enemy.png').convert()
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
    def update(self):
        window.blit(self.image,(self.x,self.y))

#Player
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = 100
        self.height = 25
        self.image = pygame.image.load('graphic\\sprite\\spr_player.png').convert()
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
    def update(self):
        window.blit(self.image,(self.x,self.y))

#Cursor
class Cursor(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.mouse.set_visible(False)
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.image.load('graphic\\cursor\\crosshair.png').convert()
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
    def update(self,enemies):
        self.rect.center = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        if (pygame.sprite.spritecollideany(self,enemies)):
            sys.exit()

#Define sprites
player = Player(500,100)
cursor = Cursor()
cursors.add(cursor)
enemy = Enemy(0,0)

#Gameloop
gameLoop = True
while gameLoop:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if (event.type == pygame.QUIT):
            gameLoop = False
        #Keydown
        if (event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN):
            #Space key
            if (event.key == pygame.K_SPACE):
                x = random.randint(0,0)
                y = random.randint(0,668)                
                enemies.add(Enemy(x,y))
            #Escape key
            if (event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE):
                sys.exit()            

    #Window color
    window.fill(blue)

    #Updating player
    player.update()

    #Updating enemy
    for enemy in enemies:
        enemy.x += moveX
    enemy.update()
    enemies.update()
    enemies.draw(window)

    #Updating cursor
    cursors.update(enemies)
    cursors.draw(window)

    #FPS
    clock.tick(60)

    pygame.display.flip()
pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to change the position of the `pygame.sprite.spritecollideany()` command from your update function to your while loop, remove the parantheses around the command, and change the command to `pygame.sprite.spriteCollide()` so it looks like this:

```
import pygame
import random
import sys
import os
from pygame.locals import *

#Initialize pygame
pygame.init()

#Window properties
window_width = 1366
window_height = 768
window = pygame.display.set_mode((window_width,window_height),pygame.FULLSCREEN)
pygame.display.set_caption("Sniper")

#Clock
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

#Movement
moveX = 1
moveY = 0

#Colors
black = (0,0,0)
white = (255,255,255)
blue = (0,0,64)

#Sprite groups
enemies = pygame.sprite.Group()
cursors = pygame.sprite.Group()

#Enemy
class Enemy(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = 25
        self.height = 100
        self.image = pygame.image.load('graphic\\sprite\\spr_enemy.png').convert()
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
    def update(self):
        window.blit(self.image,(self.x,self.y))

#Player
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = 100
        self.height = 25
        self.image = pygame.image.load('graphic\\sprite\\spr_player.png').convert()
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
    def update(self):
        window.blit(self.image,(self.x,self.y))

#Cursor
class Cursor(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.mouse.set_visible(False)
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.image.load('graphic\\cursor\\crosshair.png').convert()
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
    def update(self):
        self.rect.center = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

#Define sprites
player = Player(500,100)
cursor = Cursor()
cursors.add(cursor)
enemy = Enemy(0,0)

#Gameloop
gameLoop = True
while 1:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if (event.type == pygame.QUIT):
            gameLoop = False
        #Keydown
        if (event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN):
            #Space key
            if (event.key == pygame.K_SPACE):
                x = random.randint(0,0)
                y = random.randint(0,668)
                enemies.add(Enemy(x,y))
            #Escape key
            if (event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE):
                sys.exit()

        if pygame.sprite.spritecollide(cursor, enemies, True):
            sys.exit()

    #Window color
    window.fill(blue)

    #Updating player
    player.update()

    #Updating enemy
    for enemy in enemies:
        enemy.x += moveX
    enemy.update()
    enemies.update()
    enemies.draw(window)

    #Updating cursor
    cursors.update(enemies)
    cursors.draw(window)

    #FPS
    clock.tick(60)

    pygame.display.flip()
pygame.quit()
```

The explanation for these changes are that by moving the `pygame.sprite.spritecollide()` command into the while loop, you can make contact with *any* enemy in any position and still activate your sys.exit(). The `pygame.sprite.spritecollide()` needs three things in its parantheses: the variable you put your function in (`cursor = Cursor()`), the sprite group you are colliding with (`enemies = pygame.sprite.Group()`), and the True/False in the third (since your statement is that as long `gameloop = True` the game still runs, so True will be put in the third part.) This should fix your problem and if not then I hope you find an answer soon! Also, I recommend using `while 1:` or `while True:`!

Comment: Thanks for the comment PythonMaster, but that does not work. I did what you had said and the first problem that comes up is "bool" object is not callable, meaning the True that was put in there. When I remove the True, the game runs just as it did when I first asked here.

Comment: You did only use `pygame.sprite.spritecollide` right?

Comment: Sorry! I forgot to change the command to `pygame.sprite.spritecollide()`. That must be the problem. I have edited my answer to actually be correct this time...

Comment: No, that didn't work either. It still is the same as when as what I started with. I'll keep looking.

Comment: Have you tried changing from `while gameloop:` to either `while 1:`or `while True:`?